# Magento 2 Cloning an order and modifying few things

Tags: magento-2.1, sales-order, model

All I'm asking here is the right direction on how to accomplish this,

I'm basically trying to clone an order and modify the following:

- increment_id
- remove some line items
- on any line item:

  - modify name/title
  - set price to zero
- remove payment data

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want keep original Order as it is. And want to get that Order data somewhere else?

Comment: without payment data how you please order

Comment: a clone that has only the product names and qty, and customer name, "-1" added to the end of increment id, nothing else pretty much. in the same site.